# How to change random number of random elements in a column by group in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
>df
   Name
 1 Ed
 2 Ed
 3 Bill
 4 Tom
 5 Tom
 6 Tom
 7 Ed
 8 Bill
 9 Bill
10 Bill
```

My goal is that from each group by "Name" change the "Name" values 25-75% of random rows to "Name"+"_X" (the remaining rows don't change). So the expected output is similar to:

```
   Name
 1 Ed
 2 Ed_X
 3 Bill_X
 4 Tom
 5 Tom_X
 6 Tom
 7 Ed_X
 8 Bill
 9 Bill
10 Bill_X
```

I have tried with for cycle like this (a the moment, for 50% random rows:

```
for (n in unique(df$Name)){
  df[sample(which(df$Name==n), nrow(df[df$Name==id,])/2), 1] <- paste(df$Name, "_X", sep="")
}
```

Unsuccessfully, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct, even if you have a couple of mistakes in your code (like id is not defined, and inside paste you want to use just n, not df$Name). This is not super compressed code but it does the job:

```
Name = c('Ed','Ed','Bill','Tom','Tom','Tom','Ed','Bill','Bill','Bill')
df = data.frame(Name)

for (n in unique(df$Name)){

    # get indices 
    indices = which(df$Name==n)

    # sample size
    samp_size = round(length(df[df$Name==n,])/2)

    # get indices to replace
    samp = sample(indices, samp_size)

    # need to set column as character
    df$Name = as.character(df$Name)

    # set new values
    df[samp,] =  paste(n,'_X',sep='')

    # set again column as factor 
    df$Name = as.factor(df$Name)
}
```

Out:

```
     Name
1      Ed
2    Ed_X
3    Bill
4   Tom_X
5   Tom_X
6     Tom
7    Ed_X
8    Bill
9  Bill_X
10 Bill_X
```

Comment: If you want to select sample_size also randomly, you can use round(runif(1, min=25, max=75)) which will return an integer between 25 and 75, and then use this value to calculate samp_size